# How to POST key/value pairs instead of a JSON Object using Spring for Android?

Tags: android, spring, rest, post, http-post

I am trying to use Spring for Android to do a standard HTTP POST to a url where the body of is just a list of parameters (like key-value pairs) and not a JSON object.

I would like the response to be converted from JSON to the Java ResponseObject, but from what I can tell, Spring is also converting my body into JSON as well.

Here is my code:

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    params.put("client_id", mClientId);
    params.put("state", mState);
    params.put("username", mUsername);
    params.put("password", mPassword);
    return getRestTemplate().postForObject(url, params, ResponseObject.class);
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: can you provide the expected response body and current one ?

Comment: what is your restTemplate configuration in `applicationContext.xml` or similar config file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

posting simple name value pair list

```
// Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
try{
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", nameString));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Country", "country name"));
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
httpclient.execute(httppost);
}catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `.exchange()`

```
// Create the request body as a MultiValueMap
MultiValueMap<String, String> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();     

body.add("client_id", mClientId); // and so on

// Note the body object as first parameter!
HttpEntity<?> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<Object>(body, requestHeaders);

MyModel model = restTemplate.exchange("/api/url", HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity, MyModel.class);
```